# Implementing Git on an existing project

Tags: git

I have a project that has a significant amount of files and directories that will be created. Luckily, it is in the beginning stages of development.

My intent is to move this project to Git, but my experience is limited to pulling from, committing to, and pushing to an already existing Git setup.

According to my research, here is some information that may help determine the best way to set this up.

- 2 Developers
- 1 Remote Server (the live web server)
- 1 Website

I would like to have two branches, one that we push to actively, suppose it's called "dev", and one that, once I verify everything, gets pushed to live, I would assume called "master", by default.

The web files are located at

```
/home/user/public_html
```

I would like to create the repository in a a separate directory so it doesn't flood the public_html directory with Git-related files.

Does anyone know of any good tutorials or have any solid recommendations on how a command-line noobie can get Git rolling?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question anywhere in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know of any good tutorials or have any solid recommendations on how a command-line noobie can get Git rolling?

There are a few places you can look for good "getting started" type stuff. There's the [Git tutorial](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html) that's included as a man page with Git itself and the [reference guide and free, online book](http://git-scm.com/documentation) available from git-scm.com. I've also written a [series of blog posts](http://shotgunsandpenguins.blogspot.com/2009/07/journey-to-git-part-idistributed-vs.html) which several people have found helpful in taking them through their first steps with Git.